# How split a string and modify the current element

Tags: javascript, node.js

[Nodejs] I have a string

`var value = "The beautiful home"`

I would iterate on it and modify element.

```
value.split(new RegExp(/[\s]/gm)).forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (element == "home") {
    value[index] = "dog";
    // change home with dog
  }
});
```

I want change the "home" with "dog" but the program doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: See [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), it may help. Or do you have some reason for splitting into an array?

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not a proper problem description

Comment: you have splitted with space but never assigned to value.

Comment: doesn't work means that the string is the same "The bautiful home".

Comment: Strings are immutable, so it will not change. You can only create a new one.

Comment: value.string creates a new string, you are modifying the new string but that does not modify the old string

Comment: `value = value.replace(/\bhome\b/g, 'dog')` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you have splitted string tat needs to be stored as array.and then oly you can assign value.you cant directly change strings because strings are immutables

```
value = value.split(new RegExp(/[\s]/gm));
 value.forEach(function(element, index) {
  if (element == "home") {
    value[index] = "dog";
    // change home with dog
  }
});
value = value.join(' ');
console.log (value);
```